# Notation of bits in C

Tags: c, octal

I'm reading "The C Programming Language" and in the section on bitwise operations they write things like:

```
x & ~077
```

What do the 7s in 077 stand for?

Comment: It's octal base number as identified by the initial `0`: `077` = `0*8*8 + 7*8 + 7` = `63` = (`111111` in binary) = (`3F` in hexadecimal)

Comment: Octal digits exactly represent three binary digits (000 = 0, 001 = 1, ... 111 = 7).

Comment: comes from the early days when some machines has bits in multiples of 3 rather than 4 (pdp11 for example) for chars, ints, ptr....

Comment: @pm100: When I worked on a PDP-11 in college the convention of using octal was rather annoying, as the word size was 16 bits. I would think hexadecimal would have been more convenient.

Comment: `077` is an octal representation of decimal number `63`

Comment: The main places where octal is still used are in Unix (POSIX) file permissions, and in C code when you write `0` (because `0` is an [octal number](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1), not a decimal number, though the result is the same) or `'\0'` or similar.  Otherwise, it has largely and justifiably fallen by the wayside.

Comment: @FredLarson yup I meant PDP8, I just finsihed a PDP11 emulator in rust so you would think I would know the word size :(

Comment: @pm100: I'm on a serious nostalgia trip now. Sigh.

Comment: There were 36-bit and 60-bit machines too, which meant that the values used an integral number of octal digits — whereas 'powers of two' architectures use a fractional number of octal digits (2⅔ for 8-bit; 5⅓ for 16-bit; 10⅔ for 32-bit, 11⅓ for 64-bit, etc) but an integral number of hex digits.

Comment: In addition to Jonathan's comment on Unix file permissions: It is quite handy to use octal numbers, because the file permissions are coded in sets of 3 bits. So each digit stands for one set, see [chmod](https://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/chmod/).

Comment: Octal numbers aside `~077` is probably a bad idea since the integer constant `077` has type signed `int` and by doing bitwise inversion you end up with a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

In C, any number literal beginning with "0" and followed by digits between 0 and 7 (inclusive) is a value in octal notation. That is, the numeral base if 8.

So the number "077" has the decimal value of:

- 0 * 8²
- + 7 * 8¹
- + 7 * 8⁰
- = 0 + 56 + 7
- = 63

Or, as binary value with leading zeroes: "000111111".

The octal system was in wider use in former CS times, before the hex(adecimal) system took over. Both of these numeral systems have the advantage that each digit represents a set of bits. An octal digit stands for 3 bits, and a hex digit stands for 4 bits. A value in decimal notation cannot be "translated" simply digit-by-digit.

This is not the place to teach you the basics of number systems, you might want to read the [Wikipedia page on positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) to start with learning.